# How to separate text lines from txt files in python?

Tags: nlp, pandas, preprocessing, python-3.x

I am playing with a `.txt` file in Python for EDA and I want to separate the lines from this fashion:

```
Corona Virus = Justin Piper

COVID19 = Piper, Justin
Fed Paper Says Companies May Automate More Jobs During Pandemic https://t.co/SUqrMfpNJY

Donate the money 
Might put food on plate 
And smile on face
```

to this fashion:

```
[['Corona Virus = Justin Piper'],['COVID19 = Piper, Justin
Fed Paper Says Companies May Automate More Jobs During Pandemic https://t.co/SUqrMfpNJY'],['Donate the money 
Might put food on plate 
And smile on face ']]
```

I tried `.split('\t')` but it is taking each line as a new row.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file line by line, discard blank lines, and wrap the lines that are left by a list to get the same as your desired result

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    print([[x.strip()] for x in f.readlines() if x.strip() != ''])
```

By doing `[x.strip()]` you clear the whitespace at the beginning and end of the file and then wrap it in a list, and the condition `x.strip() != ''` makes sure that the line actually contains content and is not just a blank line.